# How to set the destination directory in ant zip task when using zipfilesets with refids?

Tags: ant

I am building a zip file using ant. The zip task includes a lot of zipfilesets that are just references.  I would like to place all these referenced filesets, not at the root (i.e. ./) in the resulting zip, but at a subdirectory, say mysubdir.  I currently have the following:

```
<zip destfile="myzip" >

    <zipfileset refid="core2lib.zfs"    />
    <zipfileset refid="core-lib.zfs"    />
    <zipfileset refid="samples.zfs"     />
    <zipfileset refid="tools2bin.zfs"   />
    <zipfileset refid="top.zfs"         />
    <zipfileset refid="top2lib.zfs"     />
    <zipfileset refid="doc.zfs"         />
    <zipfileset refid="wpmlbuild.zfs"   />
    <zipfileset refid="wpmllib.zfs"     />
    <zipfileset refid="license-other.zfs"       />
    <zipfileset refid="license-government.zfs"  />
    <zipfileset refid="license-external.zfs"    /> 
</zip>
```

which places all file sets at ./.  I've tried putting a prefix="mysubdir" on the zipfilesets as in

```
    <zipfileset refid="core2lib.zfs" prefix="mysubdir"  />
```

but this causes the following error message:

```
    "You must not specify more than one attribute when using refid"
```

So, how do I put all these filesets at some other location in the resulting zip (hopefully without building a separate tree in the file system) without modifying all the referenced file sets?

Comment: have you tried zipgroupfileset?

Comment: I don't think zipgroupfileset is what I want since I'm not starting with a zip file, but rather a tree of files.  I've found a way to do what I want but it means modifying each fileset definition to include the prefix.  For example...
`
<zipfileset id="db.zfs" dir="../database/sql" prefix="${shortname}/database/sql">
 <include name="*/**/*.sql" />
</zipfileset>`